# How to Design Switching Circuit Using Comparator

Tags: batteries, comparator

How do I create a comparator circuit that compare voltage from 12V battery when the battery drain to a certain level, let say drain to 1.5v, the comparator will produce an output that will trigger relay for other circuit.

I have a project using comparator. My task is to change from main battery to backup battery when main battery drain to certain level.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? We are not personnal designer, show us what you tried and we will try to help you from that point.

Comment: i have tried design by using voltage divider. is it possible if i want the comparator to produce output when input voltage is lower than reference voltage?

Comment: @MrAkuGitar It is best to add a sketch.  Hit Edit and on top you will see a circuit editor.  You will have to do some research on battery. 1.5V from 12V does not make sense.  If it was a 12V lead acid battery, it would be considered completely discharged at 10.7V.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the comparator route, You need a fixed voltage reference which works down to the 1.5V, and a moving voltage reference which trips the comparator at 1.5V.

Use a 1.1V Reference Voltage Zener Diode as one input for the comparator, and the slowly reducing input voltage from the battery system to the other input.

The op-amp will need it's own supply to work properly all the way down to 1.5V, so you could try a small low power auto buck-boost converter to provide 3.3V all the way down to 1.2V or so input and up to say 16V input (hard to find, probably expensive, good luck).

The set point for the comparator is 1.1V, the monitored input can be voltage-divided down so that when it reaches the required level, the comparator trips.

Be aware that you will need to protect the comparator inputs from over-voltage, using Zener clamps and series resistors - if you have 12V being monitored, and very little or zero voltage dividers going on, the input to the op-amp will be damaged if you just directly connect it - the ESD protection diodes internally will burn out and the device will be compromised.

I have recently designed and simulated a system like this for the purpose of under-voltage lockout of a Lipo battery system, but the outputs are also suitable for triggering a power-path change via relays etc. (with the appropriate relay interface circuit from the comparator's digital low power output).

Comment: can u help me with the circuit design??

Comment: @MrAkuGitar no, sorry. Try finding comparator circuits online and do some learning yourself - bring us a nice new question with your attempts at the circuitry and we can help you once you have a schematic. Remember to reference this question/answer in your new question.